# ValueError: Ciphertext with incorrect length

Tags: python, rsa, pycryptodome

I have a problem that reads:
"Suppose your RSA public-key factors are p = 6323 and q = 2833, and the
public exponent e is 31. Suppose you were sent the Ciphertext 6627708. Write a program that takes the above parameters as input and implements the RSA Decryption function to recover the plaintext."

When trying to get the ciphertext decrypted I recieve the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-bb484f24f99a> in <module>
----> 1 cipher.decrypt((str(ciphertext)))

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Crypto/Cipher/PKCS1_OAEP.py in decrypt(self, ciphertext)
    165         # Step 1b and 1c
    166         if len(ciphertext) != k or k<hLen+2:
--> 167             raise ValueError("Ciphertext with incorrect length.")
    168         # Step 2a (O2SIP)
    169         ct_int = bytes_to_long(ciphertext)

ValueError: Ciphertext with incorrect length.
```

My code currently looks like:

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_OAEP

n = 17913059
e = 31
p = 6323
q = 2833
d = 13861087
ciphertext = 6627708

key = RSA.construct(rsa_components=(n,e,d,p,q))
cipher = PKCS1_OAEP.new(key)

cipher.decrypt((str(ciphertext)))
```

I was wondering more so if I am on the right track, or completely going off the rails. I am not too sure how to fix the length error. I was thinking maybe I need to pad like in AES, but I am not too sure. Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Almost certainly your plaintext is not padded and I doubt your instructor wants or expects you to use *any* RSA library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `c`, `d`, and `n`, you can use the [RSA formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)#Decryption) to get the ciphertext:

```
>>> pow(ciphertext, d, n)
205
```

This seems like a misformed message (they're usually hex or ASCII values) so this might be just an example problem.

Your issue stems from [pycryptodome's implementation](https://github.com/Legrandin/pycryptodome/blob/24e99330a70ce3ee7933e0b1fe1ef0b8633032cd/lib/Crypto/Cipher/PKCS1_OAEP.py#L160) of [RFC 7.1.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3447#section-7.1.2), which states:

> C: ciphertext to be decrypted, an octet string of length k, where k = 2hLen + 2

where:

> hLen denotes the length in octets of the hash function output

So, technically your ciphertext is too short to be decrypted by RSA.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help. It is just a simple integer that we want to attempt to use RSA to decrypt, do you have any idea about the error or how to fix it?

Comment: @Dylaloo the problem is because of one of the FIPS or RFC's (I can't remember which) which pycryptodome follows to the letter. See my answer for how to decrypt your ciphertext